# Anemometer Gauge - how to draw numbers for the indicators?

Tags: swiftui

[image: gauge - my progress so far]

[image: gauge - how it should look like]

I am relatively new to SwiftUI, although I am fairly familiar with UIKit. I am working on a project where I will display a value (wind direction in degrees) that I receive from a wind sensor and display on a gauge.

I managed to create the gauge itself but at the moment I am stuck on how to display the numbers. Here is my code, my anemometer at the moment and what it should look like with the numbers.

Any good advice, or at least some good articles?

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnemometerView: View {
    
    //shape for the indicator arrow
    struct Triangle: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            var path = Path()

            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))

            return path
        }
    }
    
    struct MyShape : Shape {
        var sections : Int
        var lineLengthPercentage: CGFloat
        
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            let radius = rect.width / 2
            let degreeSeparation : Double = 360.0 / Double(sections)
            var path = Path()
            for index in 0..<Int(360.0/degreeSeparation) {
                let degrees = Double(index) * degreeSeparation
                let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
                let innerX = center.x + (radius - rect.size.width * lineLengthPercentage / 2) * CGFloat(cos(degrees / 360 * Double.pi * 2))
                let innerY = center.y + (radius - rect.size.width * lineLengthPercentage / 2) * CGFloat(sin(degrees / 360 * Double.pi * 2))
                let outerX = center.x + radius * CGFloat(cos(degrees / 360 * Double.pi * 2))
                let outerY = center.y + radius * CGFloat(sin(degrees / 360 * Double.pi * 2))
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: innerX, y: innerY))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: outerX, y: outerY))
            }
            return path
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader{ geometry in
                
                let width: CGFloat = min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height)
                //let height = width
                Circle()
                    .fill(.black)
                    .shadow(radius: 10, x: -10, y: 10)
                //STBD color
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: 0.167)
                    .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: width/20)
                    .padding((width/20)/2) //it gives half of the stroke width, so it is like a strokeBorder
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 270))
                    
                //PORT color
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: 0.167)
                    .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: width/20)
                    .padding((width/20)/2)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 210))
                 
                //indicator holder
                Circle()
                    .fill(.gray)
                    .scaleEffect(x: 0.09, y: 0.09)
                    
                //part of the indicator
                Circle()
                    .fill(.white)
                    .scaleEffect(x: 0.04, y: 0.04, anchor: .center)
                //angle indicators
                //long indicators
                MyShape(sections: 12, lineLengthPercentage: 0.2)
                    .stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: width/90))
                //short indicators
                MyShape(sections: 36, lineLengthPercentage: 0.1)
                    .stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: width/90))
                    //.scaleEffect(x: 0.95, y: 0.95)
                //gauge numbers
                
                //indicator arrow
                Triangle()
                    .fill(.white)
                    .scaleEffect(x: 0.04, y: 0.5, anchor: .top)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 63))
                    
            }
            //that centers the shape
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)

        }
    }
}
struct Anemometer_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnemometerView()
    }
}[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puNpX.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbPN9.png)
```

There are different solutions on internet but either are very specific or I don't understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach, where you add the gauge numbers using a set of `GaugeMarker`
and a `LabelView` within a `ForEach` loop as shown in the example code.

You will need to adjust the position and numbers according to your needs.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        AnemometerView()
    }
}

struct AnemometerView: View {
    
    //shape for the indicator arrow
    struct Triangle: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            var path = Path()
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
            
            return path
        }
    }
    
    struct MyShape : Shape {
        var sections : Int
        var lineLengthPercentage: CGFloat
        
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            let radius = rect.width / 2
            let degreeSeparation : Double = 360.0 / Double(sections)
            var path = Path()
            for index in 0..<Int(360.0/degreeSeparation) {
                let degrees = Double(index) * degreeSeparation
                let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
                let innerX = center.x + (radius - rect.size.width * lineLengthPercentage / 2) * CGFloat(cos(degrees / 360 * Double.pi * 2))
                let innerY = center.y + (radius - rect.size.width * lineLengthPercentage / 2) * CGFloat(sin(degrees / 360 * Double.pi * 2))
                let outerX = center.x + radius * CGFloat(cos(degrees / 360 * Double.pi * 2))
                let outerY = center.y + radius * CGFloat(sin(degrees / 360 * Double.pi * 2))
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: innerX, y: innerY))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: outerX, y: outerY))
            }
            return path
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader{ geometry in
                
                let width: CGFloat = min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height)
                //let height = width
                Circle()
                    .fill(.black)
                    .shadow(radius: 10, x: -10, y: 10)
                
                //STBD color
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: 0.167)
                    .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: width/20)
                    .padding((width/20)/2) //it gives half of the stroke width, so it is like a strokeBorder
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 270))
                
                //PORT color
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: 0.167)
                    .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: width/20)
                    .padding((width/20)/2)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 210))
                
                //indicator holder
                Circle()
                    .fill(.gray)
                    .scaleEffect(x: 0.09, y: 0.09)
                
                //part of the indicator
                Circle()
                    .fill(.white)
                    .scaleEffect(x: 0.04, y: 0.04, anchor: .center)
                //angle indicators
                //long indicators
                MyShape(sections: 12, lineLengthPercentage: 0.2)
                    .stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: width/90))
                
                //short indicators
                MyShape(sections: 36, lineLengthPercentage: 0.1)
                    .stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: width/90))
                //.scaleEffect(x: 0.95, y: 0.95)
                
                // gauge numbers <--- here
                ForEach(GaugeMarker.labelSet()) { marker in
                    LabelView(marker: marker, paddingValue: CGFloat(geometry.size.width * 0.80))
                        .position(CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 2))
                }
                
                //indicator arrow
                Triangle()
                    .fill(.white)
                    .scaleEffect(x: 0.04, y: 0.5, anchor: .top)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 63))
            }
            //that centers the shape
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        }
    }
}

// --- here
public struct LabelView: View {
    let marker: GaugeMarker
    let paddingValue: CGFloat
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(marker.label)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .font(Font.custom("Didot-Bold", size: 30))
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -self.marker.degrees))
                .padding(.bottom, paddingValue)
        }.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: marker.degrees))
    }
    
}

struct GaugeMarker: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    let degrees: Double
    let label: String
    
    init(degrees: Double, label: String) {
        self.degrees = degrees
        self.label = label
    }
    
    // adjust according to your needs
    static func labelSet() -> [GaugeMarker] {
        return [
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 0, label: "▼"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 30, label: "1"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 60, label: "2"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 90, label: "3"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 120, label: "4"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 150, label: "5"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 180, label: "6"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 210, label: "7"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 240, label: "8"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 270, label: "9"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 300, label: "10"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 330, label: "11")
        ]
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

minor simplifications to `LabelView` and make the font size dependent of the width of the view. Also updated the GaugeMarker `labelSet()`.

```
 // gauge numbers <---
 ForEach(GaugeMarker.labelSet()) { marker in
     LabelView(marker: marker, geometry: geometry)
         .position(CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height / 2))
 }
 
 public struct LabelView: View {
     let marker: GaugeMarker
     let geometry: GeometryProxy
     
     @State var fontSize: CGFloat = 12
     @State var paddingValue: CGFloat = 100
     
     public var body: some View {
         VStack {
             Text(marker.label)
                 .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                 .font(Font.custom("Didot-Bold", size: fontSize))
                 // make sure the text is upright, ie undo the rotation
                 .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -marker.degrees))
                 .padding(.bottom, paddingValue)
         }
         // place the VStack (with the Text) at the chosen angle around the clock
         .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: marker.degrees))
             .onAppear {
                 paddingValue = geometry.size.width * 0.7
                 fontSize = geometry.size.width * 0.05
             }
     }
 }

struct GaugeMarker: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    let degrees: Double
    let label: String
    
    init(degrees: Double, label: String) {
        self.degrees = degrees
        self.label = label
    }
    
    // adjust according to your needs
    static func labelSet() -> [GaugeMarker] {
        return [
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 30, label: "30"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 60, label: "60"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 90, label: "90"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 120, label: "120"),
            
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 240, label: "120"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 270, label: "90"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 300, label: "60"),
            GaugeMarker(degrees: 330, label: "30")
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works like a charm..almost. So it solved the main problem with the numbers, which is great. One thing is that I am not sure how exactly this works :) Could you please share some light on how did you choose this approach? Second thing is that the font-size is fixed and if I want to use this view somewhere else and needs to be small, the font stays big and view is ruined. I tried to wrap this in GeometryReader and make the font-size dependable on the width of the screen but it didn't work because it is rather offset than staying in the center of the screen. Any solutions?

Comment: Glad it helped. The approach is the one I used before, where I needed a clock with different numbering, eg digital numeral or roman numeral etc...
There must be a lot of other ways, this is just my way. For the font size, you can have 
 a dynamic size using some `@State var fontSize...` that you pass to a function that calculates the appropriate size based on your overall view dimensions. Note, this just an approach, you need to customise the code for your own purpose.

Comment: The idea is to have a set of `GaugeMarker`, each has a text label and an angle around a circle (a clock)
 where it should be placed. The centre of the circle is the centre of the view and the top (12 o'clock)
 is angle zero. The `ForEach` loops through the labelSet() and each `GaugeMarker` label is placed
 at its designated angle around the clock. The `paddingValue` controls how far inside the
 circle the labels are placed.

Comment: Updated my answer with minor simplifications to `LabelView` and to make
 the font size dependent of the width of the view, very basic I know.

Comment: Awesome, thank again, that was a great answer and neat solution. Works exactly as I expected to! Tried different views and it is always resized as it is supposed to be.