# PickerView Custom in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, pickerview

I need to implement horizontal picker view.

I've tried to rotate UIPickerView, but it's not work poerfect because problem is that big distance between elements and it is possible to change selected item when scroll stops, not when it is scrolling.

Is the right way to do it?

[i need picker view like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0iGg.png)

Comment: This may be helpful: https://iosexample.com/tag/speedometer/ OR https://medium.com/@langheashish389/building-a-speedometer-app-with-swiftui-a-step-by-step-guide-70fd702a02b7

Comment: have a look at Apple Gauge, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gauge  towards the end of the doc. See also this SO post/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76917858/anemometer-gauge-how-to-draw-numbers-for-the-indicators